# Is it necessary to close a file opened in a function?

Tags: r

The variable `x` refers to an opened file in the function `f()`. The variable `x` goes away once the call to `f()` is finished. But will the opened file closed or it is hanging somewhere but just not accessible anymore.

```
R> f=function() { x=file('f.R', 'r'); print(isOpen(x)); }
R> f()
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Just a guess, maybe it would stay locked for editing outside R?

Comment: Yeah, just tested it, it stays read only. So the answer is "Yes" :)

Comment: How did you test a variable that is local to a function. Could you provide the code?

Comment: Same as your code, opened existing file with your function. Then tried to edit the file using text editor, it won't let me save. But once I ran `close(file("f.R"))` I could edit/save it.